# Make menu appear when div is at top of window - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a single page website the is basically 4 large divs. The first is a landing section. As the user scrolls down the page id like to have a navigation menu animate from the top of the 2nd div called about. That menu will then stay fixed to the top of the window. What is the best way to find when a div hits the top of the window while scrolling? Any advice on the best way to do this would be greatly appreciated! Please see the fiddle for basic page structure.

http://jsfiddle.net/aartese/3kRVm/11/

```
  <body>   
   <div class="row"><!--landing section -->
     <div class="col-md-12 landing">Landing</div>
   </div> <!-- /landing section -->
   <div class="row"><!--about section -->
    <div class="col-md-12 about">About</div>
   </div><!-- /about section -->
   <div class="row"><!-- professional profile section -->
    <div class="col-md-12 professional">Professional</div>
   </div><!-- /professional profile section -->
   <div class="row"> <!-- contact section -->
    <div class="col-md-12 contact">Contact</div>
   </div> <!-- /contact section -->    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so that it might be good solution for you that is

html:

```
<div id="menu">top menu </div>
```

css:

```
#menu {
width : 800px;
height : 50px;
background-color:blue;
position: fixed;
display : none;
}
```

script:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
$('#menu').toggle($(this).scrollTop() > 80);
});
```

You can now add animated option in jquery.

Comment: I really like this solution! Using the toggle with scroll works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, i'm not sure If I like using the set height for scrollTop() since that changes if you changed the window size, right? I'll try drips solution.

Answer (score 3):

You check the div offset().top with the $(window).scrollTop().

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#sample').offset().top){
        $('#sample').addClass('black');
    }else{
        $('#sample').removeClass('black');
    }
})
```

Here is a demo: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NNTaT/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to streetcoder for putting me in the right direction. I slightly modified his solution:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var divHeight = $('.landingBackground').height();
  $('.navbar').toggle($(this).scrollTop() > divHeight);
});
```

This gets the height of the first main div(.landingBackground). It then toggles the menu according to that height when you scroll.

Comment: whoops, thought I did! There you go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm getting what you want.......

Does the About-Div gets fixed all the time? In this case you'll want to you the position:fixes-property of css.

If you only want to have it fixed once you scrolled pass your first div you have to determine that divs size and then chekc (via Javascript) if you reached its bottom via document.body.scrollTop